# Suitable pattern and type of the object returned in Observable<T> after a post operation

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, rxjs, observable

According to the [Angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request), I'm supposed to returned the posted object. It makes sense in the example because we want to work with the entity that has been saved to the DB.

In my particular case, I'm not interested in the objected that I post. In fact, the object is a wrapper consisting of a bunch of unrelated junk. At the backend, there's a series of *void* invocations starting up by the post. At the moment, I do subscribe in the service and it's a fire-and-forget based logic.

In an attempt to improve the quality, I'd like to tell the component that the requested operation went well by a code, like this. I control the endpoint of the API so I can produce a number or an object there.

```
fireAndForget(junk: Junk) : number {
  ...
  this.http.post<number>(url, body)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
    .subscribe(yey => return yey, neh => return -1);
}
```

In the component, I hope to be able to get the result and react to it accordingly like so.

```
const junk: Junk = { ... };
const result = this.service.fireAndForget(junk);
if(result > 0) doStuff(); else doOtherStuff();
```

However, I can't shake the sensation that I'm breaking a pattern or tamper with best-practice here. I have a hunch that I should return an observable (still of type *number* not *Junk* corresponding to *Hero[]* in the guide). The component needs not know the stored object. Just a tiny bit of info on how it went.

Provided the above, is there a recommended, widely applied, type for passing the outcome that I'm not familiar with?

Comment: The main issue with `const result = this.service.fireAndForget(junk);` is that it's async. `if(result > 0) doStuff(); else doOtherStuff();` will effectively always execute before the previous line is complete. This is usually why the caller (component usually) would `subscribe()` to indicate the Observable<T> from the service has `emitted/failed/completed`. Also returning from within `subscribe()` will not actually return anything, instead you'd use RxJS operators such as `map()` to project the result to whatever type/value you'd need.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I might be confused/confusing so let me reiterate what I was going for. In the service, the async operation that I subscribe will be completed when *yey* is passed to the handler. That *yey* will be whatever I put in *return Ok()* on the backend, e.g. the number 1337. I notice that *yey* is equal to 1337, after its realization and then, I want to handle it by emitting it up to the component. Do I need to return type *Observable<number>* from *fireAndForget*? Can I then use *fireAndForget(junk).map(...)* in the component?

Comment: I'd say it's common practice to yes return a type of `Observable<whatever>` from the service using pipeable operators such as `map()`. I'd say you more rarely see `subscribe()` used in the service method. This gives the control to the caller, such as a component. This is a matter of opinion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

If you are not interested in the return type of the post method, then you can return a number to ensure the return type is same:

```
fireAndForget(junk: Junk) : number {
  ...
  this.http.post<number>(url, body)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
    .map(yey => return 1);
}
```

And in the component you can subscribe to the method call, like this:

```
const junk: Junk = { ... };
const result = this.service.fireAndForget(junk)
               .subscribe(yeh=>doStuff(),neh=>doOtherStuff());
```

**Option 2:**

If you do not care about the return type and want to differentiate if the request was processed successfully or not. The this following approach will work:

```
fireAndForget(junk: Junk) : number {
  ...
  this.http.post<number>(url, body)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
}
```

in your component:

```
const junk: Junk = { ... };
const result = this.service.fireAndForget(junk)
               .subscribe(yeh=>doStuff(),neh=>doOtherStuff());
```

Comment: I don't see where the number is issued to the subscriber in the second example. Please elaborate.

Comment: The return type for the service method in both option 1 and option 2 would be Observable<number>, not just number.

Comment: @DonkeyBanana, as per the code sample provided, you are trying to returning -1 if there is an exception. And then check if it is -1, the run something. Rather, you can put the method execution in the catch block itself. In Option 2, doStuff() will be executed when the http method does not return any exception and doOtherStuff() will be executed if the http method threw an exception.